# MS access event load form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, events, load

I have about 20 MS-Access databases with about 400 Forms and wish to perform an action whenever any form is loaded.
I would need, perhaps, an event at database or application level that would trigger at any form being opened/loaded. Then I might need only to add code once to each of the 20 databases, but not to each of the 400 forms.
And: it has to be in VBA (Access >= 2010)!
My Question: Is this even possible? And if so, does someone have a hint?
Thanks, 
Pete

Comment: How is each form loaded? Are you manually loading the form at runtime based on some user interaction? Or is the user using the built-in navigation within Access to load each form?

Comment: The forms are being loaded by a great variety of user interaction (I didn't write the package myself).  I just have to add certain capabilities everytime a form is opened/loaded.  A DB-event such as "Form_Load (pForm As Form)" would have been perfect, but doesn't seem to exist. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to go about this, I think.

What I'd probably do is the following:

1. Create a hidden form that opens whenever your database opens (using an autoexec macro) with a timer.
2. When loading the hidden form, initialize a collection/multi-level array of all available forms in the database, and set their status to closed (somewhat difficult, probably would go with multilevel array or a collection inside a collection to be able to store form name + boolean open or closed).
3. Periodically iterate the collection, check for changes, so you can see whenever a form closes and trigger your event.

You could also use VBA to iterate through all the forms, add a module to them if there is none, and then add your desired `Form_Load` code to that module. (Would probably be wise to simultaneously create code to undo that action, so you can actually maintain the code). While refining that, you could check if the form already has a `Form_Load` action, and append code to that if it exists.

Alltogether, possible, but difficult. If you want pointers on some of the steps, I can give them, but for major issues on the implementation, I'd ask a separate question.

Comment: OK, I could use VBA to access the VBE Object and modify code.  It does work in Excel and I have done that, but I didn't really consider that to be particularly stabile.  And Access is i.m.h.o. certainly not stabiler than Excel...  But it might be a possibility. Thanks in any case.

Comment: Never encountered any instability doing that myself. It does require exclusive access to the database, but it's only a one-time modification. But as said, my preference would be the first one (the form that periodically checks open forms).